# How do I turn dots into triangles?

Tags: image, algorithm

I'm trying to programmatically make an image of triangles all stuck together. The way I thought I'd approach this problem is by randomly choosing some number of points, then "connecting" them to make triangles. The problem is that I'm not able to come up with a good way of connecting them.

One thing I though about doing was choosing a random point to start with (point 1), then finding the nearest point (point 2) and then "connecting" them. Then, I'd find a nearest third point by choosing the one whose combined distances from point 1 and point 2 is the lowest. This will give me one triangle. I can repeat this until I have a bunch of triangles. The problem here is that the triangles will be separate (they won't be connected).

Am I stupidly over-thinking this? Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)!

What it basically does, is to group three points in a triangle, if the circle that passes through them doesn't contain any other point, and it does it efficiently. There would be special cases with points on one line, or more than 3 points on the same circle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track to start, think of that first step as creating 3 edges, then you take each of those edges and make a new triangle with an additional point on each.  Theoretically, you should have 2 triangles per edge.